# React.useState doesn't save info when I use firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I want to get some data from firebase real-time database. I have this:

```js
function useGetDatabase(firebase) {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
  const [loadin, setLoadin] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    function get() {
      setLoadin(true);
      console.log(firebase.getFavoriteCharacters().once("value"));
      firebase.getFavoriteCharacters().once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        setCharacters(snapshot.val());  //Here I save data in characters with useState
        console.log(snapshot.val());   //Returns data, the output is: [1,2,3]
      });
      setLoadin(false);
    }
    get();
    console.log(characters);   //Doesn't save data, the output is: []
  }, []);
  setCharacters([1]);   //If a put it outside of useEffect it works
  return { characters, loadin };
}
```

Why that doesn't save my data?

Comment: You are logging a stale closure. setCharacters does not mutate characters so you can't just log it. You could try `setCharacters (c=>console.log(c),c)`

Comment: Yeah, but its not my problem. My problem is in ```setCharacters(snapshot.val())``` because it is not saving data, so when a call ```characters``` is empty

Comment: Could you try to do `setCharacters (c=>{console.log('characters:',c); return c;})` right after you setCharacters with snapshot.val()? I don't think you understand how asynchronous works because you log something before the asynchronous action has finished and that would always be an empty array (even without logging stale closure). However; if you log within the `.then` callback in the way I suggest you would see it is set.

Comment: Can you recommend me a page for understand asynchronous pls?

Comment: Maybe [this chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/async%20%26%20performance/ch3.md) can help you understand how promises work.